# How can i direct to another page in laravel (AdminLTE Template)?

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5, custom-routes, adminlte

i already installed template AdminLTE in my laravel app.
but i not totally understand how to direct my slidebar menu to direct page.

ex:

```
<li><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-calculator'></i> <span>Calculator</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set in the **href=** url that you want redirect to.

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/some url ...')}}"><i class='fa fa-calculator'></i> <span>Calculator</span></a></li>
```